# Changing android package name throughout the Manifest file

Tags: android, api, xamarin, package-name

My project name contains ".", so the package name is not really valid since it was "P.C.P.P.C.P" (my project name is "P.C.P").

I edited it in the AndroidManifest.xml and it works pretty well- the pakcage name is now valid and the app runs perfectly on my phone.

- Note that I use Xamarin and not Android Studio.

So is it actually valid to change the package name in this way?

Comment: So, whats your question exactly?

Comment: Is changing my package name via the Manifest file might cause problems?

Comment: No. That’s one way to do it, so you are fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your package name for your Xamarin app, you need to manually change the package name by going to the `AndroidManifest.xml` and change the package attribute.

The `AndroidManifest.xml`file is available under

```
[Solution Name]>[App Name]>Properties>AndroidManifest.xml in your solution explorer.
```

The app will then need to be rebuilt for the package name change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
By the way, what happens if there are 2 projects with the same pakcage name? Is it something I need to worry about?

Comment: Well, the main prooblem is that you can't install 2 application with the same app name, or upload it to the PlayStore

Comment: So, when I will face such a problem, i'll just have to change my package name?

Comment: I can say that my package name is like the app's id? So services and system could distinguish between the two?

Comment: Yes, each application has a different package name

Comment: Thanks a lot, Muito obrigado!

Comment: No problem (De nada ! :)